# Create/register a shortcode in PHP on HTML tags

Tags: php, jquery, shortcode

I want to create a shortcode to style existing content on a page.

```
function myShortcode(){    
    $mycontent = '<div class = "columnstyle">'; 
    $mycontent .= ...existing content wrapped in a <p> tag... 
    $mycontent .= '</div>';
    return $mycontent;
}
add_shortcode('columnstyle', 'myShortcode');
```

The existing 'p' tag:

```
<p class='first'>blah blah blah</p>
```

How do I assign $('.first') to $mycontent? I don't think this is working...

```
$mycontent .= $('.first');
```

**Update:**

I knew $('.first') is a javascript variable as I didn't know how to reference it in PHP. The next function I am going to carry out is:

```
function myShortcode_call(){    
    ?>        
        <script type="text/javascript">                
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){                     
                $('.first').before("<?php echo do_shortcode('[columnstyle]'.myShortcode().'[/columnstyle]');?>");

            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('thesis_hook_after_html','myShortcode_call');
```

The result is to style the content "blah blah blah" on the page with the short code [columnstyle].

Comment: `$('.first');` looks like jquery to me.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yeah, but I still have no idea what's supposed to be what in this question.

Comment: @deceze He don't think it's working, that's the issue, lol, it was just the escape stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Are you working with wordpress?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

```
function myShortcode($shortcode){    
    $mycontent = '<div class = "columnstyle">'; 
    $mycontent .= $shortcode;
    $mycontent .= '</div>';
    return $mycontent;
}
add_shortcode('columnstyle', 'myShortcode');

function myShortcode_call(){    
    ?>        
        <script type="text/javascript">                
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){                     
                $('.first').before("<?php echo do_shortcode('[columnstyle]'.myShortcode().'[/columnstyle]');?>");

            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('thesis_hook_after_html','myShortcode_call');
```

Comment: the first solution didn't work out, see my comment on the first post. "first" is just a class name I randomly came up. However, with your second solution, it looks like the <p>content</p> is hardcoded into the function, am I understanding right?

Comment: Are you trying to get the content inside of columnstyle into myShortcode? Look at my edit..

Comment: Yes, you read my mind! This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks so much! the edit portion is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by

```
$mycontent .= '$(".first")';
```

when you use below

```
$mycontent = $('.first');
```

you will get error  below

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' on line bla
```

Comment: or you escape your `'` like `$mycontent .= '$(\'.first\')';`

Comment: Or `$mycontent .= "\$('.first')";`

Comment: :-) or `$char='\'';$mycontent .= '$('.$char.'.first'.$char.')';` (just a joke)

Comment: I tested the backslash as well as the add another single/double quotes outside $('.first'), the result from "view page source" shows: <script type="text/javascript">                
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){                     
                    $('.first').before("<div class = "columnstyle">$('.first')</div>");
                     
                });
            </script>

Comment: It didn't wrap the 'columnstyle' div tag around 'first' p tag, nor it did the styling.